# 2014 Putnam A1 Prime number factorial help

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-writing, contest-math

Question:

> Prove that every nonzero coefficient of the Taylor series of $(1-x+x^2)e^x$ about $x=0$ is a rational number whose numerator (in lowest terms) is either $1$ or a prime number.

Solution:

> The coefficient of $x^n$ in the Taylor series of $(1-x+x^2)e^x$ for 
>   $n=0,1,2$ is $1,0,\frac{1}{2}$, respectively. For $n\geq 3$, the coefficient of 
>   $x^n$ is
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{n!} - \frac{1}{(n-1)!} + \frac{1}{(n-2)!}
> &= \frac{1-n+n(n-1)}{n!} \\
> &= \frac{n-1}{n(n-2)!}.
> \end{align*}
>   If $n-1$ is prime, then the lowest-terms numerator is clearly either 1 or the prime $n-1$ (and in fact the latter, since $n-1$ is relatively prime to $n$ and to $(n-2)!$).
>    If $n-1$ is composite,
>   either it can be written as $ab$ for some $a \neq b$, in which case both $a$ and $b$ appear separately in $(n-2)!$ and so the numerator is $1$,
>   or $n-1 = p^2$ for some prime $p$, in which case $p$ appears in $(n-2)!$
>   and so the numerator is either 1 or $p$. (In the latter case, the numerator is actually 1 unless $p=2$, as in all other cases both $p$ and $2p$ appear in $(n-2)!$.)

I just need some understanding help.

Considering the case where $n-1$ is composite is where I have the problem.

$$n-1 = ab$$ Where $a, b \in \mathbb{N^+}$

Look carefully here:

> If $n-1$ is composite,
>   either it can be written as $ab$ for some $a \neq b$, **in which case both $a$ and $b$ appear separately in $(n-2)!$** and so the numerator is $1$.

Q - How can you ensure that $a,b$ appear in $(n-2)!$ later on? Since,

$$(n-2)!= (n-2)(n-3)...(1)$$

I can see this is true for $n=8$, but I don't see a way to prove it.

Looking here:

> $n-1 = p^2$ for some prime $p$, in which case $p$ appears in $(n-2)!$
>   and so the numerator is either 1 or $p$. (In the latter case, the numerator is actually 1 unless $p=2$, as in all other cases both $p$ and $2p$ appear in $(n-2)!$.)

Q - How can you say, $n-1 = p^2$ for sure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How much verbosity. You have already proved that the coefficient of $x^n$ is:

$$\frac{(n-1)^2}{n!} = \frac{(n-1)}{n(n-2)!}.$$
Now, two cases: if $n-1$ is a prime, there is nothing to prove. Otherwise, $(n-1)=ab$ with $1\leq a< b\leq n-2$ unless $(n-1)$ is the square of a prime. So we can assume $(n-1)=p^2$ and we have to prove that:
$$ \frac{p^4}{(p^2+1)!} $$
is of the given form. If $p=2$ we are ok. If $p\geq 3$, then $p,2p,3p$ are less than $p^2+1$ and we are ok, too.

Comment: (+1) I like your 1st sentence also =) How do you justify, $a, b < n-2$. How can you prove that without speculation? Since $n-2 = n-1 - 1$ it does obviously make sense that $a, b < n-2$ otherwise $n - 3/2$ is a factor of $n-1$ which is impossible to have $n -1 \in \mathbb{N}$ right?

Comment: @Amad27: exactly, all the proper divisors of $n-1$ belong to $\left[1,\frac{n-1}{2}\right]\cap\mathbb{Z}$, and $\frac{n-1}{2}$ is for sure less or equal than $n-2$.

Answer (score 1):

$a$ and $b$ are at least $2$, so $(n-1)/a=b<(n-1)/2$ and vice versa. For $n \geq 4$, $n-2>(n-1)/2$, and since $(n-2)!$ contains every number between 1 and $n-2$ as a factor, it must include $a$ and $b$.

For the second bit, if $n-1$ is composite, it has a factorisation of the form $n-1=ab$. If $a=b$ and $a$, say, is composite, then you can shift one of the factors of $a$ into $b$ and produce a factorisation with $a \neq b$. If $a$ is prime, so is $b$, and so $n-1=p^2$